# How can i set text like "Help" and "Support" in android

Tags: android

I am new to android. I want to write "Help" & "Support" in  xml but an error occure when I am trying to write this in xml . How can I solve this problem.

Comment: add your code and the error that you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi manisha in Xml  (") symbol should be written as (&quot) and  (&) symbol should written as (&amp)
put semicolon after the &quot and &amp

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Help &amp; Support.
```

The `&` sign should be escaped before using in an XML file

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters) to see a list of characters that should be escaped to be used in XML.

Answer (score 0):

Use string escape sequences at these cases \"Help\" & \"Support"